# R: Concatenate rows to make an statement for any dimension

Tags: r, concatenation, paste

I¨m trying to convert somo variables to statements.

I´m loonking for some variables in a data frame like that:

```
y<-subset(x,x$Incidence.type == "Appro.11.Plural")

     Invoice        Incidence.type
 1: 20171200738 Appro.11.Plural
 2: 20171200737 Appro.11.Plural
```

Once it is done, I would like to set an statement like that:

```
Statement<-paste("The invoices",y[1,2],"and",y[2,2], "are...")
```

The problem is that the number of elements, instead of two, could be from 0 to infinite. So, I need to generalize this code to achieve an equivalent result, whatever the number of invoices.

I´ve try that, but still not working:

```
  if (length(y>0) {for (j in (Push$Invoice)) {Statement<-paste(j,sep = ",")}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

0 and 1 are special cases, anything 2 and over we can generalize.

```
if (nrow(y) > 0) Statement = "No matches."
if (nrow(y) == 1) Statement = paste("The invoice", y[1, 2], "is ...")
if (nrow(y) > 1) {
    invoices = paste(y[, 2], collapse =  ", and ")
    Statement = paste("The invoices", invoices, "are ...")
}
```

I've mimicked your question using the second column of `y`, but don't you actually want the invoice number? For more robust code I'd recommend using the column name: `y[1, "Invoice"]` instead of `y[1, 1]`, that way you will always get the correct column even if the order is different. If you are using `data.table` you don't need to quote the column name.